# How to create pie chart in pandas over different ranges of values from single column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-visualization, data-analysis

For example i have this following data

```
City           Population

abc            5000
mno            2000
xyz            7000
uvw            9000
def            11000
```

I need pie chart for this with three categoies , underpopulated where population < 5000, moderate-populated where 5000 < population < 10000, and overpopulated where population > 10000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're looking for this (oneliner)

```
# import module and create dataframe
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'City':['abc', 'mno', 'xyz', 'uvw', 'def'], 'Population':[5000, 2000, 7000, 9000, 11000]})

# create pi chart
df.assign(Label = pd.cut(df.Population, [0, 5000, 10000, 99999], labels=['low', 'mid', 'high'])).groupby('Label').sum().Population.plot(kind='pie')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

using pd.cut, create the bins, then use groupby to group population and finally draw the pie

```
labels = ['under','moderate','over']
df['grp'] = pd.cut(df['Population'],
                   (0,5000,10000,100000) , 
                   labels=labels)

plt.pie(df.groupby(['grp'])['Population'].sum(), labels=labels)
```

[image]